# Retaining leading zeros in Array output rephrased

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to retain leading zeros in an array output that uses Variant and Long data types.  When I try to switch the D variable to a String, I get a type mismatch error.  An additional problem is that the number of leading zeros needs to be flexible as values range from 4 to 9 digits in length.  I am pasting the entire sub below, along with a screen shot of the input values and results.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

```
Sub ExpandRanges()

Dim ArrayData As Variant
Dim ArrayOut As Variant
Dim X As Long
Dim D As Long
Dim Index As Long

ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B3").NumberFormat = "@"

ArrayData = Range("A1:B3")

ReDim ArrayOut(1 To Evaluate("Sum(B1:B3-A1:A3+1)"), 1 To 1)

For X = 1 To UBound(ArrayData)
    For D = ArrayData(X, 1) To ArrayData(X, 2)
        Index = Index + 1
        ArrayOut(Index, 1) = D
    Next
Next

With ActiveSheet.Range("D1").Resize(UBound(ArrayOut), 1)
.Cells = ArrayOut
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `NumberFormat` should be something like "0000000000" for a 10-digit string which retains the leading zeroes.